# Webpack и настройка путей к файлам и картинкам

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

Всем привет.
Я новичок в программировании и недавно столкнулся с неразрешимой для себя проблемой:
[Пост с проблемой:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839228/nuxt-js-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) 

После многодневных попыток решить данную задачу - во многих источниках мне сказали что решить данную проблему можно копая в сторону webpack.

Вопрос:
Поскольку данных скилов у меня нет пока что - я планирую изучить этот инструмент.
Но!
Мне необходимо знать точно могу ли я потом решать такого уровня задачи c ним?

Может ли вебпак при деплое или после него в отдельной процедуре - исправить пути к файлам картинкам и т.п.?
Если да то какой уровень компетенции требуется для решения данного рода задач?
(можно ли сходу после углубленного курса какого нибудь или прохождения гайда на оф сайте - решить эту проблему?)


 + какую версию Webpack учить необходимо - если как я понимаю nuxt.js использует не последнюю версию.
(На сколько я понимаю используется версия 3.12)

P.S. Буду благодарен за любые конструктивные коменты..

Comment: Да, Vue (и тот же Nuxt) из коробки использует webpack 3.*, И вебпак автоматически при деплое заменяет пути к файлам. С Nuxt не работал, но с vue-cli да (не думаю, что там есть большие отличия). Смысл в том, что есть две разных конфигурации вебпака для dev и prod окружения. Когда ты ведешь разработку в режиме dev - сервер вебпака автоматически вставляет нужную статику по временному пути, но когда ты деплоишь - вебпак вставляет в разметку нужные ссылки на статику. Это в настройках `./config/index.js` есть параметры `assetsRoot`, `assetsSubDirectory`, `assetsPublicPath`

Comment: К сожалению такой папки(config) найти не удалось у себя в проекте(Nuxt.js).
А из тех файлов что пересмотрел визуально - параметров описаныых вами встретить тоже не удалось.

Comment: Поиск данных параметров по всему проекту(в IDE) - также не дал позитивных результатов..